# Can't keep session ID via CURL PHP

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm writing a function to fetch the captcha, of course it needs to keep the session. I'm using cookie file for curl and use it for every request but it does not work. When I view the cookie file, I see that the PHPSESSID changed each time I call the function. How could I solve it?

Here is my code

```
<?php    
function fetch_captcha($url, $cookie_file = false, $user_agent = DEFAULT_USER_AGENT, $timeout = 10) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    if ($cookie_file) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
```

`PHPSESSID` is a session cookie, and this option causes each `cURL` call to start a new session, so it ignores all session cookies in the file.

Comment: I have removed this line but the PHPSESSID still change each time I call this function :(

Comment: Ok, I found the problem, that is I re-create the cookie file before each time I call this function. Thank you so much!